# when editing UITextFiled the text jumps

Tags: ios, uitextfield

i'm creating a UITextField programmatically, and when im clicking it and starting to edit the text, the text jumps a few pixels up then down (with each click). when i'm done editing, it goes to the center, where it actually suppose to be.

```
self.phoneTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, quarterScreen * 3.0f, textFieldHeight)];
    self.phoneTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    self.phoneTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    self.phoneTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.phoneTextField.placeholder = @"Enter Phone Here...";
    self.phoneTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    [self.phoneTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    self.phoneTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    [self.phoneTextField setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
    [self addSubview:self.phoneTextField];
```

can anyone help me fix this issue? thanks.

Comment: In which method you call this code? What are you doing in the TextField delegate methods?...

Comment: this code is called from initWithFrame, on start. and i'm implementing 
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
where inside i check each time the string (character) inserted by the user

Comment: What is your textfield's height?

Comment: its 81.142....
got it with CGFloat textFieldHeight = self.screenRect.size.height / 7.0f;